# Easiest way to make a dynamic 'assessor' or 'quiz'

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, css

I was working on a Joomla website with mainly HTML + CSS. I'm learning Java, but have barely any experience in JavaScript, though when reading the code I can eventually understand it.

All I wanted to simply do is create a custom HTML module on a page with:

A assessor. So this would work like this:

Options A and B in buttons. 
Clicking A > 2 more options (A1 and A2)
Clicking B > 2 more options (B1 and B2)
Clicking any (A1, A2, B1 or B2) will lead to its own individual content appearing.

This is intended to happen on the same page, hence it being dynamic.

I would imagine the buttons to have a toggle feature, which upon click would lead to hiding or showing linked div, or something like that.

Now I'm looking for the EASIEST way to do this. I don't mind: 
- writing this manually through an editor 
- installing a Joomla plugin that can do this for me.

I would prefer coding this, but if an off-the-shelf solution exists, it would save time.

Please let me know what you think, and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a paid extension, but I would use RSForms Pro.  It is super easy/fast to throw together something like that since it has the ability to put free text fields in it and a built in tool for conditional fields so you can hide/show options based upon previous choices.
https://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-form.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create your own Joomla Module.

You can use this tool:

http://ibrini.com/en/services-accueil/modules

To create an empty module that later you can use to incorporate your code.

Hope this will help you.